# Blending transition in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

In my cocos2d-iphone game, I have 2 backgrounds (CCnodes), each containing a quite complex hierarchy of sprites.

I would like to make a smooth transition between them:

- Initially, only the first background is visible
- At the end, only the second one is visible

Is there a good way to set the opacity of a full hierarchy of sprites ?

I tried to recursively set the opacity of all the contained sprites. It kinda works except that:

- I guess it's not very efficient
- I would like the opacity of overlapping sprites to be 'merged' (as if the background was one single big sprite)

Comment: You can render one node to a texture and render a sprite containing  that texture some transparency on top of the other node

Comment: But what if I have animations running on the children (translations, scaling,...)

Comment: wouldn't be any problem, all children would be rendered to the texture as normal. please see this related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14073785/1436359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it using a `CCRenderTexture`.

You can find the detailed explanation here: http://2sa-studio.blogspot.com/2013/01/fading-node-hierarchy-with.html

Comment: The link is dead. But I found another one right here:
http://2sa-studio.blogspot.com/2013/01/fading-node-hierarchy-with.html